# Fullcalendar: How to change the display of the month?

Tags: javascript, ajax, calendar, fullcalendar, jquery-events

Calendar works great:

[image]

But the need to be able to bring mini calendar:

[image]

How could modify the calendar in this form?
I see it through `eventRender` and other methods, but do not quite understand how.

The main difference in the calendars that the "big" we have shown **list** of events, and in the small to appear "popover" when you click on a particular day.

Answer (score 0):

Try height property, see http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/height/

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'list,month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,agendaList'
        },
        editable: true,
        selectable: true,
        height: 300,  // will reduce the total height of the calendar
        firstDay: 1
    });
```

Else Try  --> this works like charm and simple

```
<div id="calendar" style="width:300px;height:300px"></div>
```